# about Page Turner widget

Tags: android, android-widget

could you tell me where to down the Page Turner widget in old early sdk.i want to use it. can you give me a link?  and if  give me have been modified code,i feel more happy.
thank you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PageTurner` was removed from Android before the first open source release, and so it is no longer available.

Comment: i know it was removed,but i want to implement it

Comment: @pengwang: Then implement it. You will have to do so from scratch, and so there is no source code for you to work from.

Answer (score 1):

See source: http://jaynsw.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/page-pageturner/. Googled it and found this.